# Java Map hash code

Tags: java, dictionary, hashcode

Which is the best way to compute the hash code of a `Map`, knowing that it may contain entry values of types such as: `String`, `Integer`, `Object[]` ... ?

`Map.hashCode()` returns a shallow hash code. That means that if you have a `String[]` in your map, the `Map.hashCode()` will also use the hash returned by the `String[]`. Which, unfortunately, is not what I want (the `Object.hashCode()` implementation). But I want the `Arrays.hashCode(String[])` implementation.

So which is the best, generic, approach to handle this ?

Comment: I assume your Map is immutable?  If your adding/removing entries, your values-based hashCode() is doomed.

Comment: I think most people's initial question will be "why?"  what are you doing that you need to change the hashcode of the map?  calculating a "deep" hashcode could make that operation pretty expensive...

Comment: @Kirk Woll: please detail, what's the point ?

Comment: @John Gardner: I need to know whether two maps hold the same values, in deep. In a generic manner.

Comment: @javaq, `hashCode()` is usually used upon the key in a HashMap.  It is called, for example, when you place an entry into the map.  If you ever modify the value of a *key* such that a new invocation of `hashCode()` will return a **new** value, suddenly that key is located in the wrong table entry in the map.  This means that the map is now broken and bugs will ensue.

Comment: @javaq, a hashCode will *not* guarantee that the two maps are equal anyway -- you're barking up the wrong tree.  Two objects with different values *may* return the same hashCode().  If you want a deep equality comparison, you're just going to have to implement that yourself -- your own `equals` method.

Comment: Also be aware that Maps are allowed to contain themselves... be careful not to recurse infinitely calculating hashcodes :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you need to know if two maps contain the same values, you will need to write a deep comparison method.  you shouldn't be depending on hashCode.

even with a perfect algorithm, there's no way that every possible collection of every possible object could be uniquely represented by a single signed integer.

Hashcode is just for collision **reduction** when used in collections, it is not supposed to be used to *uniquely identify* objects.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know any other effective ways of achieving my goal ?

Comment: if you need to know that two collections are *exactly* the same, there's no real other way to do it other than a deep comparison.  things that are *not* the same can fail quickly, but worst case is always comparing every inner object, including inner comparisons of every inner collection...

Answer (score 3):

The solution to your problem is to not use arrays. Use ArrayLists (or some other form of List, like an ImmutableList from Google's Guava). Lists hash the way you want. Also, arrays don't really play nice with generics (like Maps).

Comment: This is not a solution. I cannot control the input. Eventually I could recursively replace the arrays with array lists, but I would avoid that.